# Missing required architecture arm64 in file /roject/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libQuickDialog.a

Tags: ios, xcode, arm64

I need to set up arm64 for my project.

I configured the build settings but project shows many errors like:

> d: warning: ignoring file
>   /Users/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Prj/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libQuickDialog.a,
>   missing required architecture arm64 in file
>
> /Users/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Prj/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libQuickDialog.a
>   (2 slices) Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>
> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_QRadioElement", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in DataViewController.o
>   _OBJC_CLASS_$_QEntryElement", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in DataCViewController.o
>         objc-class-ref in DataViewController.o
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_QDecimalElement", referenced from:

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: You need version of the libQuickDialog that contains the 64bit slice.

Comment: Are `QRadioElement` etc. part of your source tree?

Comment: I think so, I'm starting with IOS and I'm messed up!  Where can I find the libQuickDialog versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was set arm64 in the external project. It had two targets and I was setting it only in one of them when it has to be configured on both.